# how to implement split pdf functionality in cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa

I have implemented one desktop application in which i want to implement split pdf functionality .How it possible please advice me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you want to implement "split pdf functionality?" You mean you want to split one PDF document into separate PDF documents? If so, see [PDFKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html).